# Static IEnumerator

Tags: c#, arrays, list, static, enumerator

How to minimize the overhead by implementing an Array Wrapper?

1 Which Interface/Type to choose for **MyProviderInfos**?

2 <s>Is that reasonable to use **private static** enumerator?</s> NO, from the
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13378456/503677)

3 <s>Should **MyProviderInfos** be a property and how to protect its members from modifications?</s> internal/private SETTERS for members (from the same answer)

I tried going through SO articles about ICollection, Readonly-Collection, List, IList, Array, but still confused what would be best for the scenario:

- The Array MyProviderInfos is formed by the compile time and will not (must not) be changed at the run-time.
- The Class is (must be) Enumerable (with Elements of the Array MyProviderInfos) and Custom List functions (.Add .Remove) are NOT necessary.
- The class HAS static functions, which use the Array.
- The class MUST be non-static to support Indexing.

Code:

```
 public class MyIdentifiers : IEnumerable<MyProviderInfo>
 {
   //public static IList<MyProviderInfo> getMyProviderInfos() 
   //{ return MyProviderInfos; }

    public static int MyProviderCount()
    {
        return MyProviderInfos.Count;
    }

    public static readonly IList<MyProviderInfo> MyProviderInfos = new[]
    {
        new MyProviderInfo
            {
                MyProvider = MyProvider.FirstProvider,
                Url = "https://www.google.com",                       
            }
    };

    private static IEnumerator<MyProviderInfo> _enumerator = 
((IEnumerable<MyProviderInfo>)MyProviderInfos).GetEnumerator();

    public IEnumerator<MyProviderInfo> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _enumerator;
        //return ((IEnumerable<MyProviderInfo>)MyProviderInfos).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which Interface/Type to choose for MyProviderInfos?

Unless you want to limit features directly visible to your users you should always return the *less generic* type (in your case the array itself).

As general rule it's a good practice to accept the most generic possible type as parameter (for example if you just want to enumerate a collection then declare that parameter as `IEnumerable<T>`) and the less generic as result (so users can use it as `IEnumerable<T>` if they just need that or as `IList<T>`, as needed, without fragile casts and conversions). Moreover, in your case, `IList<T>` supports adding items but this will throw at run-time because array is fixed size so you expose more than what they actually can do.

For example:

```
string[] ConvertToTitleCase(IEnumerable<string> names);
```

Of course you can return an `IEnumerable<string>` too instead of `string[]`, it may be appropriate if - for example - the implementation doesn't create any array for the result to avoid an extra conversion.

> Is that reasonable to use private static enumerator?

Absolutely no, an enumerator is an object with a state (take a look to any `IEnumerator<T>` implementation) then it can't be static (imagine when called by different threads, for example).

> Should MyProviderInfos be a property and how to protect its members from modifications?

It doesn't need to be a property unless you want to provide some kind of lazy initialization. To protect its members the only thing you can do is to make them read-only (it doesn't matter if the collection itself is read-only). How to do it depends on `MyProviderInfo` implementation. You may consider to do not expose any `public` setter for its properties. For example:

```
class MyProviderInfo
{
    public MyProviderInfo(Provider provider, string url)
    {
        Provider = provider;
        Url = url;
    }

    public Provider Provider
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public string Url
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}
```

Or, without too many changes, keep your existing code but make setters internal (so users of your library won't be able to modify them):

```
class MyProviderInfo
{
    public Provider Provider
    {
        get;
        internalset;
    }

    public string Url
    {
        get;
        internal set;
    }
}
```

To summarize a little bit I would rewrite that as this:

```
 public class MyIdentifiers : IEnumerable<MyProviderInfo>
 {
    public int Count
    {
        get { return _myProviderInfos.Count; }
    }

    public IEnumerator<MyProviderInfo> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<MyProviderInfo>)_myProviderInfos ).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    private static readonly IList<MyProviderInfo> _myProviderInfos = new[]
    {
        new MyProviderInfo
            {
                MyProvider = MyProvider.FirstProvider,
                Url = "https://www.google.com",                       
            }
    };
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer, Adriano, internal setters - obvious, was just confirming. I would like to know if getting Enumerator from MyIdentifiers instance will work the same (read in speed-aspect) as getting it directly from _myProviderInfos with a property get { return _myProviderInfos; }

Comment: Overhead for few function calls is hard to measure (and probably is such nano optimization that you shouldn't even care about it) anyway JIT compiler will inline it so do not worry at all (and do not forget that enumeration itself is terribly slow if compared to direct array access).